# Cannot find Skype in Software center

Tags: skype

I just upgraded mu Linux version on new Ubuntu 13.10. When I was looking for Skype in Software centre, I did not find it.

Answer (score 4):

Skype is in the Canonical partner repository. If you unchecked that it will not show up. See Dash, Software and updates:

[image]

And Skype is there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you find it easier, you can also google it "skype for ubuntu".

http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

Choose your distribution, download the `.deb` package and when you doble-click on it, you get right directed to install it through the Ubuntu sofware center. I hope it helps.